# Use Rails path helpers from inside an plain old ruby class? (Resque job)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque, urlhelper

I need to make some API calls from inside a Resque job (which is just a plain old Ruby class) and those API calls need to include URLs to resources on my site.

Is it "correct" to just add this to my class definition?

```
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
```

Or is there an "expected" way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that is the way to do it.

http://snipplr.com/view/37063/to-access-url-helpers-urlfor-etc-from-rails-console-rails-3/

linked to from here http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/UrlWriter

Answer (score 0):

In your controller:

Rails 1.x:
`include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers`

Rails 2.x:
`include ActionController::UrlWriter`